# Discuss the convergence of sequence x_n := (n^2)(a^n) for 0<a<1 and n belongs to natural numbers.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Discuss the convergence of sequence x_n := (n^2)(a^n) for $0<a<1$ and n belongs to natural numbers.

$x_n$ is a sequence of positive real numbers and hence we can use ratio test:

$[x_(n+1)]/[x_n] = {(n+1)^2a^{n+1}}/{n^2a^n}$
$                = a{(n+1)^2/n^2}$

now,

$lim(x_{n+1}/x_n) = lim(a)*lim((n+1)^2/n^2)$
$                     = a*1$
$                     = a$

since $0<a<1$

then, 
$0<lim(x_{n+1}/x_n)<1$

therefore,
lim(x_n) = 0

hence x_n is convergent.

Is this argument correct?

Comment: Looks Gucci....

Comment: Yes, it really converges to zero and your arguments prove it

Comment: Next, do the same for $n^ka^n$ for any $k > 0$.